# Add stars rating and average to product "Review" item menu in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, rating

I'm trying to add the following: "4.5 / 5 (5 reviews)" but without the "" to the review tab for all WooCommerce products.

I've accomplished to add the stars and some text, but I cannot figure out how to make the text into "4.5 / 5 (5 reviews)". Here's the code I'm using. Just to be clear, I want to keep the stars.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_reviews_tab_title', 'add_stars_to_review_tab', 98 );
function add_stars_to_review_tab( $title ) {
    global $product;

    $average_rating = $product->get_average_rating();
    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
    $review_count = $product->get_review_count();

    if( ! empty($average_rating) && $average_rating > 0 )
        $title = '<div>' . $title . '</div>
        <div class="stars">' . wc_get_rating_html($average_rating) . ' based on ' . $rating_count. ' reviews' . '</div>';

    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:** The following code will display something like **"4.5/5 (5 reviews)"** below the review item menu title and stars in Woocommerce single product pages tabs:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_reviews_tab_title', 'add_stars_to_review_tab', 98 );
function add_stars_to_review_tab( $title ) {
    global $product;

    $average_rating = $product->get_average_rating();
    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
    $review_count = $product->get_review_count();

    if( ! empty($average_rating) && $average_rating > 0 ) {
        return '<div>' . $title . '</div>' . wc_get_rating_html($average_rating) . sprintf(
            '<div class="stars">%s / 5 (%s %s)</div>',
            $average_rating,
            $review_count,
            _n( "review", "reviews", $review_count, "woocommerce" )
        );
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! Only problem is that now the stars are gone. If you could please add them back I would appreciate it.

Comment: @WooDevil Can you please clarify your question, as we don't know what you want exactly… do I keep reviews, the stars and the rest in 3 lines? because you will have redundent things as the number of reviews after the title (by default)

Comment: my apologies if it was unclear. Yes, please keep the stars (`wc_get_rating_html`) and underneath them, add the `"4.5 / 5 (5 reviews)"`part.

Comment: Yes, the title stays ;) I've changed that anyway using a different function.

Comment: @WooDevil I have re-updated the code, as the average rating value was rounded before… Now it displays a float number, instead of an integer.

Comment: thanks, makes all the difference and it looks better. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add star rating and average to product "Review" item in WooCommerce with just few clicks.

[Rating Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVIZ3.png)

I recently found TrustFeed reviews for WooCommerce, it is a new plugin that helped me to replace the basic and boring WooCommerce reviews forms with an advanced and dynamic rating and reviews solution that actually inspire shoppers to buy more!

It comes with special features to help honest online businesses to collect and showcase customer reviews to boost sales, conversions, trust and social proof.

Some special features are:

- Create custom satisfaction surveys

  - Star Ratings
  - Dynamic Tags
  - Text Reviews
  - More coming…
- Send Mail After Purchase emails to encourage shoppers to leave reviews.
- Collect reviews at scale.
- Showcase reviews on key conversion points of your website.
- Display your reviews in an useful, responsive and customizable format.
- Moderate and manage feedback/reviews.
- Create a mini-site to increase your SEO with User Generated Content
- Customize widget’s look and feel.
- Learn from data driven insights

The plugin is free and can be dowloaded via official WordPress plugin repository:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/trustfeed-reviews-and-customer-feedback-for-woocommerce/

- To learn more about TrustFeed you can visit www.trustfeed.co
- To view the admin panel, just login at https://admin.trustfeed.co and create a free account.